# Load image with border at the same time

Tags: swift, kingfisher

I would like to know, is it possible to load image at the same time with border? For example, I have cell where are all posts. When user posts image, the border is there before image itself.

Like this I set image inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.feedImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
let url = URL(string: postsArray[indexPath.row].postImageUrl)
cell.feedImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

And like this I set some appearance:

```
func updateUICell(imageView: UIImageView, radius: CGFloat) {
        imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
        // corner radius
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = radius

        // border
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: how is your `setImage` func look like?

Comment: I am using the Kingfisher library, so the first code in question is How I set image :)

Comment: put the imageborder code after the image loaded dispatch

Comment: That did the trick :)